# Install latest version of Node.js using Meteor Up (MUP)

Tags: node.js, meteor

By default, Meteor Up (MUP) installs `v0.10.25` of node.js if no value is entered for `nodeVersion` in `mup.json`

```
// WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.25 by default. Do not use v, only version number.

  "nodeVersion": "0.10.26",
```

**Question:** How can you configure MUP to install the latest version of node without having to enter the specific version number in `mup.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor always does not work with the latest version of NodeJS. So, having something like that is not good. So, it's better to set it manually. We'll update correct defaults. So, it's better to update mup and do a `mup setup` when you are bumping up new Meteor versions.